# GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator does not exist with Hangfire.Ninject

Tags: ninject, hangfire

I have been using `Ninject` and `Hangfire` for a while and just added the `Ninject.Hangfire` package. However the following extension method just doesn't seem to be loading despite having updated both all 3 of these packages.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio triggered it to work.

I think it could be because `Hangfire` and `Hangfire.Ninject` both use the `Hangfire` namespace (which is where `UseNinjectActivator` is defined).

So something just isn't refreshing.